# How to read file in slack api in python?

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I want to read file uploaded by user to a channel in Slack Api. I am using "app_mention" event and whenever a user mentions an app name and upload a csv file, I use a function to catch this even in the back-end. Below is my python function:

```
@app.event("app_mention")
def reply_to_mention(event, client, logger):
"""

"""
print("reply2mention")
try:
 
    for i in event['files']:
        try:
            if i['url_private_download']:
               
                df = pd.read_csv(i['url_private'])
                #df = pd.read_csv(i['url_private'],header=None ,sep='\n')
                #df = df[0].str.split(',', expand=True)
                print(df.shape, df.head(1))
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            continue
    text = f"Thanks for the mention, <@{event['user']}>! How can I help?" + event['text'] + '<@' + event[
        'user'] + '>'
    client.chat_postMessage(channel=event['channel'], text=text)
except Exception as e:
    logger.error(f"Error responding to app_mention: {e}")
```

The event dictionary : i['url_private'] has the url of the download link to csv but I get "Error tokenizing data" error since the content is not csv. It seems the function is downloading the html code rather than the csv. Is there a way I can access the data uploaded by a user in a function like above?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to read the uploaded files:

```
# Class for passing bearer authorization token
class BearerAuth(requests.auth.AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.token = token
    def __call__(self, r):
        r.headers["authorization"] = "Bearer " + self.token
        return r
url=''
token=''
r = requests.get(url, auth=BearerAuth(token))
file_data = r.content   # get binary content
file_name="test.csv"
# save file to disk
with open(file_name , 'w+b') as f:
    f.write(bytearray(file_data))
print("Saved " + file_name + " in current folder")
df=pd.read_csv("test.csv")
df.head()
```